# How to fix this Implementation that doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

The users repository implements IUsersRepository, although i cant get the values from IUsersRepository

[The error that is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOJiH.png)

UserRepository implementing the IUserRepository Interface

```
import { getRepository, Repository } from "typeorm"; 
import { IUsersRepository } from "../IUsersRepository"; 
import { User } from "../../entities/User";
import { ICreateUserDTO } from "../../../../dtos/usersDto";

class UsersRepository implements IUsersRepository {

    private repository: Repository<User>;
    
    constructor() {
        this.repository = getRepository (User);
    }

    async create({ name, email, password, age }: ICreateUserDto): Promise<void> {
        const user = this.repository.create({
            name,
            email, 
            password,
            age
        }); 
        await this.repository.save(user);
    }

    async findBy Email(email: string): Promise<User> {
        const user = this.repository.findByEmail({ email }); 
        return user;
    }

    async findById(id: string): Promise<User> {
        const user = this.repository.findById(id); 
        return user;
    }
    
export { Users Repository }
```

IUserRepository Interface:

```
import { ICreateUserDTO } from "../../../dtos/usersDto", 
import { User } from "../entities/User";

interface IUsersRepository {
    create (data: ICreateUserDTO): Promise<void>; 
    findByEmail(email: string): Promise<User>; 
    findById(id: string): Promise<User>;
}

export { IUsersRepository }
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`findByEmail` is not function of typeorm's `Repository` class.
It is even marked with a red line in your screenshot.
You need to write the proper query there!

Comment: But I used findByEmail and findById because I was implementing the interface IUsersRepository.

Comment: Please post your code as code and not as screenshot. Your class has member variable `private repository: Repository<User>` and you are calling `this.repository.findByEmail({email})`.  Like I said `Repository` from typeorm has no such method